# React Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasChildNodes' of null

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasChildNodes' of null` in my react app when I do this -

```
this.props.history.push('/search');
```

I am using `react` `16.2.0` and `react-router-dom` `4.2.2`

My routes are defined as follows -

```
           <Switch>
                <Route          exact    path="/login"           component={Login}       />
                <PrivateRoute   exact    path="/"                component={HomePage}    />
                <PrivateRoute   exact    path="/authors"         component={Authors}      />
                <PrivateRoute   exact    path="/books"           component={Books}       />
                <PrivateRoute   exact    path="/bookDetail/:id"  component={BookDetail}  />
                <PrivateRoute   exact    path="/editBook/:id"    component={EditBook}    />
                <PrivateRoute   exact    path="/addBook"         component={AddBook}     />
                <PrivateRoute   exact    path="/search"          component={Search}     />
            </Switch>
```

My component gives error in my handle submit function when I receive the response from my API here -

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch(SEARCH_API_ENDPOINT+this.state.searchTerm, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: headers 
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
        }
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.docs);
        this.props.history.push('/search');
        //history.push('/authors') ;
        //<Redirect to='/search'/>;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        notify.show('Something is wrong with something!','error');
        this.setState({ error:error, isLoading: false })
    });
}
```

I am not sure why is this happening at all. Let me know if you want me to paste more details.

Thanks

Comment: how are you defining your routes? especially the one for the component that does `this.props.history.push('/search');`.

Comment: I have updated my question with my routes

Comment: hm.. I don't seem to notice anything weird here. can you paste code for the component with the line that causes this error?

Comment: Updated code again, please have a look

Comment: I got it working. I followed instruction from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666288/how-to-use-reacts-router-v4-history-push.

Comment: so your component wasn't inside the router?

Answer (score 0):

I would update the state when the following happens:

```
.then(data => {
    console.log(data.docs);
    this.setState(() => ({goodToRedirect: true}));
})
```

and then in render(),

```
if(state.goodToRedirect) {
    return (
        <Redirect to="/authors"/>);
}
```